# Counting patients in a hospital. (Actuarial exam)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The number of patients in a hospital is 54. Of these 29 are male and 12 are in intensive care. If among those not in intensive care 18 are female, how many males are in intensive care?

The correct answer is 5, but I have no idea how to reach that answer with appropriated set terminology.Thanks.

Comment: What is "appropriated set terminology"?

Comment: @Shailesh Does this problem actually require a Venn diagram? This looks like an elementary school arithmetic problem.

Comment: Just draw a Venn diagram. Label the disjoint pieces ($MI,MI^c,M^cI,M^cI^c$) and write down what you are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $54$ patients $-$ $29$ men $=$ $25$ women
- $25$ women $-$ $18$ women not in intensive care $=$ $7$ women in intensive care
- $12$ patients in intensive care $-$ $7$ women in intensive care $=$ $\mathbf{5}$ **men in intensive care**

Answer (score 0):

Let's translate the question step-by-step. Totally there are $54$ patients. $29$ of $54$ patients are men. So, there are $25$ patient women. $18$ of the patient women are not in intensive. Then, $7$ of them are in intensive women. Totally, there are $12$ in intensive men and women. If $7$ of the total in intensive people are men, what about in intensive women?